# Como mudar o objeto da resposta do Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Gostaria de saber como mudar o objeto da resposta no findAll do sequelize.

Utilizei o código abaixo para fazer a mudança mas não sei se no próprio Sequelize dá pra fazer.

```
then(chars => {
        chars.map(teste => console.log('TESTE', teste.dataValues))
        res.status(200).json({
            data: chars.map(char => ({
                ...char.dataValues,
                attributes: char.attributes.map(attribute => {
                    const {char_attribute: {value}, dataValues: {char_attribute, ...rest}} = attribute
                    return {...rest, value}
                })
            })),
            success: true,
            message: ''
        })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o nome que você quer pro campo? Acho que tem um jeito de fazer pelo Sequelize pra ficar *flat*, tipo `"char_attribute": 10`, mas mudando o nome assim acho que só mapeando mesmo. Só pra confirmar, esse campo é uma associação né?

Comment: Oi. Sim é uma associação. Eu não quero mudar o nome, eu quero somente tirar o "char_attribute": {"value": 10} e colocar diretamente o "value": 10.